# How to set Highcharts object configuration globaly with vue-highcharts?

Tags: vue.js, highcharts, vuejs2

I am wondering if there is a way to set chart options globally for highcharts in a vue app. I use following plugin instalation:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import VueHighcharts from "vue-highcharts";
import addFunnelModule from "highcharts/modules/funnel";
import exporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";
import offlineExporting from "highcharts/modules/offline-exporting";

exporting(Highcharts);
offlineExporting(Highcharts);
addFunnelModule(Highcharts);
Vue.use(VueHighcharts, { Highcharts });
```

I want to set options for exporting charts, so that they apply in all charts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out. To achieve this you use the setOptions function inside it you pass all properties that you want to be set Globally

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import VueHighcharts from "vue-highcharts";
import exporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";
import offlineexporting from "highcharts/modules/offline-exporting";

exporting(Highcharts);
offlineexporting(Highcharts);
Highcharts.setOptions({
  credits: {
    text: "some test",
    href: "http://destinationlink",
    style: {
      color: "black",
    },
    position: {
      align: "right",
    },
  },
});
Vue.use(VueHighcharts, { Highcharts });
```

For full list of options see
[See docs](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/global)

Comment: Can you please post a code example for your solution?

Comment: @hitautodestruct I have updated my answer, to include sample code